# Select specific with exists but still include unwanted result

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table and i tried to get table 1 which contains Job_ID which has not finish the progress in table 2 before 2/18/2019.
Table 1. [Test_Job]

### Job_ID (key)|Content

```
1263        |    Sing   
1410        |    Jump   
2309        |    Run    
3456        |    Swim
```

Table 2. [Test_Progress]

### Job_ID|Percent|Date

```
1410        |    10     |  2019-02-04   
1410        |    50     |  2019-02-11   
1410        |    60     |  2019-02-18   
2309        |    50     |  2019-02-04   
2309        |    100    |  2019-02-11   
3456        |    100    |  2019-02-18   
1263        |    20     |  2019-02-04   
1263        |    100    |  2019-02-11
```

Expected:

### Job_ID (key)|GroupID

```
1410        |    Jump
```

My SQL Query is:

`SELECT * FROM Test_Job
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Test_Progress
WHERE Test_Progress.[Percent]<100
AND Test_Progress.Date<'2019/02/11'
AND Test_Job.Job_ID=Test_Progress.Job_ID)`

But i still get this

### Job_ID (key)|GroupID

```
1263        |    Sing   
1410        |    Jump   
2309        |    Run
```

The job Sing and Run has finished before 2/18/2019 but still here. Please help me fix the incorrect point in my SQL. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `NOT EXISTS` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_Job tj
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Test_Progress tp
                  WHERE tp.Date <= '2019-02-18' AND
                        tp.Percent = 100
                        tj.Job_ID = tp.Job_ID);
```

This says to find records for which we *cannot* find a completed job entry on a date greater than 18-Feburary-2019.  Such jobs matching this condition therefore should be ones which were completed on or before this date.

Comment: your code lacks 'percent', the condition was Date <'2019-02-18' and percent<100